# multiple jquery functions not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in 1 file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add-button").click(function() {
      $.post("/test_data", $("#form-data").serialize(), function(data) {
        alert(data);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
      $('#Table tbody').append('<tr> <form action="/test_data" method="post" id="form-data"> \
                                     <td> <input type="text" name="name"> </td> \
                                     <td> <input type="text" name="address"> </td> \
                                     <td> <input type="text" name="phone"> </td> \
                                     <td> <button type="button" id="add-button"> add data </button> </td> \
                                     </form> \
                                </tr>');
    });
  });
</script>
```

What I'm trying to do here is dynamically add a row to a table.  that row should have an "add data" button and when clicked sends the fields of the form as a post method to an url called /test_data.

If I move the form into the main body of my html, this works perfectly fine.  If i leave it in the script to add the row via button click, it does nothing.  Am I missing something here to make this work ?

Thank you.

Comment: `$("#add-button").click(...)` binds a click handler to the first `id="add-button"` element that exists *at that moment*, not to elements that are created in the future. Also, you're creating invalid HTML because element IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by invalid html - the id's i have assigned are unique - "form-data" and "add-button".  are these not unique enough ?  also - is there a way to accomplish what i'm trying to do ?

Comment: You probably want to add the HTML that contains the button to the question.

Comment: If the user clicks the anchor twice that will create two rows in the table with the same IDs, won't it? (Also, you shouldn't have a `<form>` element as a direct child of a `<tr>`.)

Comment: I understand now, thank you nnnnnn

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the event is not bind on your newly append button

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('a').click(function() {
        $('#Table tbody').append('<tr> <form action="/test_data" method="post" id="form-data"> \
                                     <td> <input type="text" name="name"> </td> \
                                     <td> <input type="text" name="address"> </td> \
                                     <td> <input type="text" name="phone"> </td> \
                                     <td> <button type="button" id="add-button"> add data </button> </td> \
                                     </form> \
                                </tr>');
        $("#add-button").off('click').on('click',function() {
          $.post("/test_data", $("#form-data").serialize(), function(data) {
            alert(data);
          });
        });
    });

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#add-button").click(...)` binds a click handler to the first `id="add-button"` element that exists *at that moment*, not to elements that are created in the future. You can instead use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) with a selector as its second argument to create a delegated click handler that applies even to elements created dynamically in the future.

Also, if the anchor is adding a row to the table on every click then you would be creating elements with duplicate IDs in each row, which is invalid HTML. So you should use classes instead of IDs for these dynamic elements.

Finally, the button click handler should use `this` and DOM navigation methods to find its own form element, given that there could be more than one form created. (If you do this the form element itself doesn't really need an ID or a class to identify it.)

Putting that together:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Table").on("click", ".add-button", function() {
      $.post("/test_data", $(this).closest("form").serialize(), function(data) {
        alert(data);
      });
    });

    $('a').click(function() {
      $('#Table tbody').append('<tr> <form action="/test_data" method="post"> \
                                     <td> <input type="text" name="name"> </td> \
                                     <td> <input type="text" name="address"> </td> \
                                     <td> <input type="text" name="phone"> </td> \
                                     <td> <button type="button" class="add-button"> add data </button> </td> \
                                     </form> \
                                </tr>');
    });
  });
</script>
```

(Note also that there's no need for two separate document ready handlers in separate script elements, you can combine them into one.)

Comment: nnnnnn, thank you very much for outlining this and the thorough explanation.  It has really helped.  The one thing I noticed here is that when running this code, alert(data) does not contain the values from the form.  Does this require me to assign a class to the form to get the data ?

Comment: That `data` argument will contain the response from your server-side code.

Comment: this works perfectly fine in safari, but fails in firefox and chrome.  Is this specific to certain browsers ?

Comment: It shouldn't matter which browsers. Do you get an error in Chrome (in the console), or...?